# RXJS - Typescript - Await observable emit until another observable<boolean> is false

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I currently have a solution that looks like this:
When a user is navigating in a view an api call is executed to get the data for that specific view.
That data is in turn later on used to determine whether a dialog should appear when a user is performing an action.

At the moment the solution is working but I can think of a potential problem when a user is having high latency and performs the above action before the api request finishes.
I do not want to display a loading indicator everytime the user navigates since it bothers the hell out of me when working with systems like that. I would rather have the user wait when she/he wants to perform the action.
Additionally I do have an observable which indicates whether the api request is loading or not which I am planning to use somehow.
The Code looks likes this with small alterations of the names for clarity.

```
actionPerformed$ = createEffect(() => 
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(performAction),
        withLatestFrom(entities$),
        mergeMap(data => {
          let payload = data[0];
          let dataFromApi = data[1];
          ...
          ...
        })
```

One thought that came to mind that doesn't sound effecient was to have an operator which checks the condition and throws an error if its loading and simply retrying it after a short delay.

Do you have any better suggestions? I have been looking on delayWhen but seems uneffecient to have a delay like that. I would rather have like a "gate" that opens the stream when loading$ is set to false and the value is emitted as soon as that condition is met.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use routing?

Comment: @Yuriy Yes I do use routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the `dependent$` observable will emit a value once the `source$` observable has emitted `false`. Please see the working code in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-r3yma1?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

```
import { of, timer } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map, switchMap, take, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const arr = [true, true, true, true, true, true, false];
const source$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  map(i => arr[i]),
  tap(console.log)
);

const dependent$ = of("the other guy said false");

source$
  .pipe(
    filter(val => val === false),
    switchMap(() => dependent$),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This works on the premise that the observable is is emitting multiple values. The case I am working with will only emit a value when the user performs the action. If loading$ is true when that happens that filter will never be evaluated again. Perhaps what I am trying to achieve is not possible with any of the existing RXJS-operators and I have to build some sort of custom functionality.

Comment: Hi @Tjulu. I posted another answer. I hope this one is more similar to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the dependent observable will emit immediately because the service is not fetching data from the API yet. Then the service will start fetching data and the dependent observable will emit once the service has finished. You can see the working code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3ecq5d?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of } from "rxjs";
import { filter, switchMap, take } from "rxjs/operators";

class Service {
  loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // Initialized false, this is the initial situation before you start fetching data from the API

  fetchData() {
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    this.loading$.next(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Finished fetching data");
      this.loading$.next(false);
    }, 5000);
  }
}

class Component {
  service: Service;

  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  emitWhenReady() {
    const dependent$ = of("I'll emit when not fetching data");
    this.service.loading$
      .pipe(
        filter(loading => loading === false),
        switchMap(() => dependent$),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}

const service = new Service();
const component = new Component(service);
component.emitWhenReady(); // This guy will emit immediately because the service is not fetching data yet;
service.fetchData();
component.emitWhenReady(); // This guy will wait until the service has finished fetching data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you could use `combineLatest` instead of `withLatestFrom` somehwat like this:

```
combineLatest([
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(performAction)),
  entities$
]).pipe(
  filter(([action, entities]) => entities != null), // condition depends on entities structure
  map(([action, entities]) => {
    // doStuff
  })
);
```

This will wait for both observables to emit at least once which translates to "entities" loaded. The Filter is just there for safety. It will also take into account the last user action if there was one before the `entitites$` call finished.